# How to create a branch on tip of branch and create a separate pull request for it?

Tags: git, github

I am doing small feature changes in the same file. The changes are unrelated though, that's why they have to be in separate pull requests.

So I created a branch from my project `staging` branch:

```sh
git checkout -b branch1 staging
```

Did some work on it and created the pull request.

Now, since I will do more small changes in separate PRs, I don't want to wait for those PRs to be approved then merged and rebased until I can begin to work on the next feature. Also I would like to avoid creating separate branches based on staging and then having to deal with merge conflicts once every PR is approved (because all changes are in the same file).

Is there a way to do something like

```
git checkout -b branch2 branch1
```

Then create a PR from this branch that will only include the commits done in branch2? I tried to do it but it pushed all commits from the beginning of `branch1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above was amazing, it actually lectured me in so much about Git and GitHub but it didn't actually solve my question. However, I managed to get the outcome I desired by doing like so:
From my staging/master/main branch I create a new branch:

```sh
git checkout -b branch1
```

Then I do all the commits I need and create a PR on GitHub.
When working on my new feature and looking to reuse code from the commits on `branch1`, I create a new `branch2`.

```sh
git checkout -b branch2
```

Then, to be sure that `branch1` is up to date with `staging` I rebase `branch1` into `staging`

```sh
git rebase staging branch1
```

Then I rebase `branch2` on `branch1`

```sh
git rebase branch1 branch2
```

Now, I can do my work and commit on `branch2` and create a new PR. When editing the PR on GitHub, I can select the PR to compare `branch2` against `branch1` so that only my `branch2` commits will show up.

After `branch1`'s PR is approved, I rebase (if needed) `branch1` into `staging` and merge it. Then, I simply rebase `branch2` again on `staging` and do the same as for `branch1` when branch2`'s PR is approved.

Answer (score 4):

You can create new branch names in exactly the way you mentioned, but that doesn't have the effect you desire.  The reason for this is ... well, the reason is that Git is the way it is.  Git is complicated!  Git*Hub* try to simplify away these complications, so that when you make a Git*Hub* Pull Request—Git itself doesn't have these things; they're specific to GitHub<sup>1</sup>—GitHub try to show you something very simple.

Unfortunately, as you've seen, this simplicity is fake.  I think GitHub are actually doing a *dis*-service in simplifying things away like this.  It works great for many common cases, though, and lots of people obviously like it simplified.  But because of the way you're doing your work, you can't let GitHub pretend.  It just doesn't work.  Instead, you need to get into real Git, with all its complications.  These complications exist because they're *necessary*, for this kind of distributed development, at least in the most complicated situations (some of which you may never encounter).

---

<sup>1</sup>Other competitors to GitHub offer their own varieties of Pull Requests, because PRs are so useful.  Without PRs these competitors would never get much use.

---

#### Git is all about commits

The first thing to realize is that Git itself is not about *files*.  It's about *commits*.  Commits *contain* files, which is important to us humans, but Git cares about the *commits*.  Git is not about *branches*, either.  Commits *form* branches—well, one of several meanings of the word *branch*—but branch *names*, which is another of the several meanings of the word, just help you, and Git, *find* commits.  It's the commits that matter.

This means that the first thing you need is a solid grasp of commits.  Now, you've been *making* commits all along, but people can do this without ever learning quite exactly what a commit is, so let's be thorough here.  You might already know some or even all of this, but let's cover everything, albeit quickly:

- Each commit is numbered.  The numbers are *hash IDs:* they appear random, but are actually cryptographic checksums of the contents of the internal objects that Git uses to hold the commit data.  The checksum algorithm is the same in every Git binary, so that every Git computes the *same* ID for the same commit.  This is how the commits get spread from one Git repository to another: by hash ID.

  The commit object is specifically one of four kinds of internal objects.  The other three are *tree*, *blob* (file data), and *annotated tag*.  All four are addressed by hash ID.  Trees and blobs can be reused whenever that makes sense, but commits cannot.  Last, a commit object always holds exactly one tree object hash ID.

  You don't normally need to know the internals of a commit object.  Just remember that because the hash ID is the hash of the internal data, it's impossible—for anyone or anything, including Git itself—to *change* any part of any commit.  If you do take a commit out of the internal object database, change some part, and put it back, what you get is a new, different commit with a new and different hash ID.  The old commit remains: you have merely added *another* commit.  The old commit's hash ID still refers to the old commit.
- This means each commit has two parts: its data—a snapshot of *all* files, represented by the stored tree object hash ID—and its metadata, represented as the stuff inside the commit object.  The metadata holds information about who made the commit (name and email address), when (some date-and-time-stamps), and why (your log message).  Crucially for Git itself, the metadata include a list of *earlier* commit hash IDs.

The snapshot holds every file, but in a special format that only Git can read, and literally nothing can change (because of those hash IDs, again).  The various file contents are automatically de-duplicated (via that same hash ID trick).  This means that when you make a new commit with just one or two files *changed*, all the other files' copies take no space<sup>2</sup> because the commit is just re-using some other commit's copy.  In the end, there's only one copy of any one version of any file.  That's fine *because* it's read-only: nothing will ever overwrite that saved content.

Of course, if we couldn't write our own files, these saved snapshots would only be useful as archives.  So when we're working *with* files in Git, we don't work with the *committed* files.  We'll get back to that in a moment.

The saved hash IDs in each commit are there to let Git work backwards, from commit to earlier commit.  This is how Git can *show* us commits, which *are* snapshots, *as if* they were sets of changes.  Let's draw a simple, backwards-looking chain of commits in which each newer commit points backwards to its (single) parent commit.  We'll put the newer commits towards the right and the older ones towards the left, and because the hash IDs are big and ugly and unsuitable for humans, we'll replace them with single uppercase letters:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for the hash of the *last* commit in the chain.  This commit has a snapshot of every file.  It also has metadata: who made it, when, etc., and which commit comes earlier.  So commit `H` contains the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

Git can look up any commit (any object at all, really) by hash ID: its main database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), indexed by hash ID.  Given `H`'s hash ID—which we have to find somehow—Git will find `H`, and then use the metadata in `H` to find `G`.  Now Git has *two* snapshots.  A simple comparison of the two snapshots will tell Git what files we *changed*, and Git can then show us changes by comparing those files, ignoring all the files that *didn't* change.

Of course, once Git has used `H` to step back to `G`, well, `G` has in it the hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  So Git can turn `G`, a snapshot, into changes, by comparing with the snapshot in `F`.  Showing us the author and other metadta of `G` and its changes from `F` completes the process of showing commit `G`, after which Git can step back to commit `F`.

This obviously can go on forever, or until there's no *earlier* commit.  Eventually Git will get back to the very first commit, and that commit *won't* have an earlier-commit hash ID stored in it.  That commit is the beginning of history.  The `git log` command will stop here, if we haven't just quit out of it by now.

---

<sup>2</sup>When just one file is re-used, there's a minimal amount of space needed to hold a name and hash ID in a tree object.  A tree or sub-tree that's re-used in its entirety allows the commit or containing tree to refer to an existing tree by hash ID, though, so in some cases, there really, literally is *no space used at all* here.

---

#### Branch names find commits

Note that in order to get `git log` to start at commit `H` and work backwards, we had to tell Git the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  We need to know these "last commit" IDs.  Why don't we have Git save them in a small database?  We can associate some sort of *name*, like `feature1` and `feature2` and `staging` and so on, with each saved hash ID.

This is what branch names are: each one holds *one* hash ID.  That hash ID is, by definition, the *last* commit in that particular chain—even if there are more commits after that one, that's where *that* chain ends.

Let's draw one chain, ending at commit `H`, and one name, `main`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Now let's make a *new name*.  We have to pick some existing commit.  We can pick *any* commit, but let's start with the latest:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature1, main
```

Note that all the commits up through and including `H` are now on *both branches*.  We are, however, about to have a problem: which *name* are we using?  Let's attach a special name, `HEAD`, to just one branch name, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature1, main (HEAD)
```

This says we're "on" branch `main`: `git status` will say `on branch main`.  We're using the *name* `main` to find the *current commit*, which is `H`.  A `git log` command will start from `H` and work backwards.  The files we see in our work area are those from commit `H`.

If we want to work with the *name* `feature1`, we use `git checkout` or `git switch` to select that name:

```
...--G--H   <-- feature1 (HEAD), main
```

We're still using commit `H`, but now we're *finding* it via the *name* `feature1`.

Now let's make a new commit, in the usual way (which we haven't talked about).  Git will package up a new snapshot of files with new metadata saying that we made this commit just now.  That new commit will get an all-new, unique-to-it, hash ID,<sup>3</sup> but we'll just call it "commit `I`", and draw it in:

```
          I   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

As the last part of writing out the commit, `git commit` will *store the hash ID of the new commit in the current branch name*.  Since `HEAD` is attached to `feature1`, this means Git writes the new hash ID in that name.  This feature branch now has one commit that *isn't* shared with `main`, plus all the earlier commits that *are* shared with `main`.

We can now make another new branch, such as `feature2`.  When we do so, we can pick *any* commit as the place the name should point.  We could go back to earlier commit `G`, but that would be a bit silly.  We could go back to `H`, or we can continue on from `I`.

If we pick `H`, we might do that with:

```
git checkout -b feature2 main
```

This will create the new name pointing to the same commit as the name `main`, and attach `HEAD` to the new name:

```
          I   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- feature2 (HEAD), main
```

The *current commit* is now once again commit `H`.  The files we made and stored in commit `I` are removed from our work area; we now have the files from commit `H` instead.

Now, when we change things and make a new commit, we'll get a new commit `J` whose parent will be commit `H`:

```
          I   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          J   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Had we started `feature2` at commit `I`, we'd have this now:

```
            J   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
           /
          I   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

You might already see what's going to happen with GitHub Pull Requests.

---

<sup>3</sup>These hash IDs are so big and ugly *because* they have to be totally unique across every commit in every Git repository ever.  We can actually relax this constraint slightly—they only have to be unique in Git repositories that will eventually "meet up" with `git fetch` and `git push` and the like—but it's best if they're truly unique.

---

#### Git's index and your work-tree

(This isn't central to use of Git*Hub* and I ran out of space, so I've snipped this entire section.)

## GitHub and pull requests

When we talk about making PRs (Pull Requests) on GitHub, we need to get into the fact that we're now talking about *another Git repository*.  In fact, there are often at least *three* Git repositories involved here.  This means we need a fast overview of what `git clone` does, and how `git fetch` and `git pull` work.

#### Cloning a repository

A Git repository, as mentioned earlier, consists mostly of two databases: the *object database*, indexed by hash ID, and the *names* database, where Git keeps the branch-name-to-hash-ID table, along with tag names and all other names.

A normal repository, where you do some work. also has an index and work-tree.  Git supports so-called *bare* repositories, though, which omit the work-tree.  The server-side repositories that GitHub and other services provide are all bare repositories.  The lack of a work area allows you to `git push` to them.<sup>4</sup>

Given some existing GitHub repository, you can run `git clone` on your own computer—a laptop, say; we'll use this to distinguish it from some GitHub server—to make a copy of the bare repository.  Your copy won't be bare, but rather a working repository, so that you can do work.  You will run:

```
git clone <url> [<directory-name>]
```

Your Git will:

1. Make a new, empty directory: this is where your working tree will go.
2. Create a new, empty Git repository *in* that working tree: `git init`
3. Save that URL under a name, which defaults to `origin`.  It does this by running `git remote add name url`, where *`name`* is `origin` or whatever you chose, and the *`url`* is from the command line.
4. Run any extra `git config` commands required, if you add various options to your `git clone`.
5. Run `git fetch` with the name set up in step 3.  This has your Git call up the GitHub server.  They dump out their entire main database,<sup>6</sup> because your Git is currently completely empty.  You wind up with a full copy of every object.  They also dump the contents of their names database—but your Git takes this and *changes* it, as we'll see.  Your Git stores the *changed* names.
6. Last, run `git checkout` to create and switch to some branch.  You can control this, with the `-b` option.  If you don't, though, your Git gets a *recommended name* from their Git.  The default, if you have not set up your own, is usually `master` (old repositories) or `main` (new ones).

Steps 5 and 6 need explaining.  When they dump out their names table, it will say things like `master` or `main` is commit `a123456...` or whatever.  Those are *their* branch names.  Your Git takes these names and *changes* them, into what I call *remote-tracking names.*<sup>7</sup>  These let *your* Git remember what hash IDs *they* were storing, in what branch names they had.  Your Git can update these whenever it gets fresh information from them.

Having renamed all their branches, your Git has *no branches in it* right now.  That's not a good situation.  So your Git now *creates* a branch name.  The name your Git creates is the one you choose, or the one they recommend if you didn't choose.  Then your Git does the very first `git checkout` ever, of that branch name, to fill in your working tree and set up Git's index and have everything ready for you to use.

Five of these six commands that `git clone` runs *are* Git commands.  The other one just makes your working tree.  You can run these commands manually.  There's no good *reason* to do that: it's a lot more convenient to run `git clone` and get them all done together.  Plus, if anything goes wrong, `git clone` will clean it all up for you, as if you never ran any of those six commands.

But in the end, that's what cloning is: we make a *new* repository, and copy all the *commits* and supporting objects into it while copying-but-changing their *branch names* into our remote-tracking names.  Then we get *one* local branch: that one branch name that we get points to the *same commit* as its corresponding remote-tracking name, so that our `master` and their `master` mean the *same commit* by hash ID.  Our Git remembers *their* branches as `origin/*`, or whatever other name we chose, if not `origin`.

---

<sup>4</sup>You *can* `git push` to a repository with a working tree, but it gets messy.  Omitting the work-tree is the right way to do this, in general.

<sup>6</sup>Technically they will give you the *reachable* objects in the main database, and GitHub have all kinds of special tricks they use to save space on their side that makes this complicated, but you can just think of this as "get the objects database".  If you use a single-branch clone, or use the `--depth` or `--shallow-since` option, you can limit the set of commit and other objects further.

<sup>7</sup>Git actually calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but the word *branch* here is just cluttering up the phrase and being confusing.  I have taken to calling them *remote-tracking names* to try to cut down on the overuse of the word "branch".  (It's only slightly helpful, but I'll take it.)

---

#### Mirror clones and GitHub forks

Occasionally, it turns out to be nice to be able to do a `git clone` operation where we *don't* make our *own* branch names.  Instead, we might want to copy all of someone else's branch names wholesale.  To this end, we can make a *mirror clone*, using `git clone --mirror`.  Such a clone is a bare clone—has no working tree—and instead of *renaming* someone else's branches, just literally copies their branch names.  Because it is a bare clone, it is no good for doing work *in*, but it can be used as a sort of backup, and/or to restore some other clone (using `git push --mirror`) or for various other special purposes.

When you use GitHub's "fork a repository" button, GitHub winds up making something that acts a lot like a mirror clone: you get your own repository, with its own branch names, that is otherwise an exact duplicate of someone else's GitHub repository.  But GitHub add a few extra goodies to this.  The big one is that your clone becomes *linked* to their clone, for making Pull Requests.

#### Fetch, pull, and push

Now, suppose you have made, on your laptop, your own clone of your own fork of someone else's repository.  There are, at this point, *three* repositories of interest: the original one (on GitHub), your clone/fork (on GitHub), and your clone on your laptop.  Your laptop clone has its ow* branch names, plus the remote-tracking names that came from *branch* names in your GitHub clone.  Those branch names exist because that GitHub clone was created as a mirror clone of their repository.

Let's give the repos names.  Your Git repository *on* your laptop doesn't need a name, and your GitHub clone has a name, `origin`.  Some tutorials will suggest that you use `git remote add` on your laptop to add the URL for *their* GitHub repository, using the name `upstream`.  There's nothing wrong with all of this, and `upstream` is not a *terrible* name, but there is one catch: Git already uses the word *upstream* for something else.  Still, I'll use that here.  So you have, on your laptop, a `main` or `master` or whatever because of `origin/master` which exists because `origin` has a `master` that's a copy of `upstream`'s `master`.

*All of these names identify the same commit hash ID, and it's the commits—with their hash IDs—that matter to Git*, but humans being human, we attach all kinds of importance to the name `master` (or `main`).  Moreover, when we use `git fetch` and `git push`, we really do need to give them names!

These repositories were initially all copies of each other—in terms of commits anyway, and also with these various branch names at this point.  But once made, the copies begin to drift apart.  As people add commits to the various repositories, your laptop and `origin` may fall behind `upstream`.  Or, your laptop may get ahead of `origin`.  We *fix* these things with `git fetch`, `git push`, and Pull Requests.

Normally, each Git does everything all by itself.  It's only when we connect two Gits to each other that they *exchange* stuff.  The three commands you might use here on your laptop are `git fetch`, `git pull`, and `git push`.  The `git pull` command is kind of a red herring, and I always advise newbies to Git to *avoid* it initially: it has the name `pull` as sort of a historical mistake.  What it really does is run *two* Git commands: `git fetch`, and then one more.  The *second* command runs locally, so it's only the fetch and push commands that actually *transfer any commits*.  I recommend learning them first and separately.  This leaves just `fetch` and `push`, and these two are as close as Git gets to having opposites, here.

#### Fetch brings commits in

Let's look first at `git fetch`.  We saw it in action earlier with `git clone`: it has your Git call up some other Git.  For instance, your Git can call up GitHub, using the name `origin`, by running:

```
git fetch origin
```

Their Git will list out their branch names and hash IDs.  If there are *new* commits in the GitHub repository over at `origin`, your Git will see these hash IDs and notice: *hey, I don't have that commit!*  Your Git can then ask their Git to *send* that commit.  They will then offer that commit's *parent* commit hash ID to your Git, and your Git will check: *do I have that commit?*  If not, your Git will ask for that one too.

In this way, `git fetch` obtains, from the other Git, any and all *new* commits: commits they have, that your repository doesn't yet.  This part all works by raw hash ID.  Your Git brings over those commits—they package them up, with any files that you'll need; you see "counting commits" and "compressing commits" and so on here—and your Git gets them and sticks them in your repository.  But now you need a *name* by which to *find* these new commits.  They should, ideally, add on to the other Git's branches, so they should add on to your *remote-tracking names*.

Let's take a simple example, where in your Git, you have your own `master` that you copied from `origin`'s `master` that you're calling `origin/master`, plus a `feature1` branch in `origin` that you're calling `origin/feature1`.  So you have this locally:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \
          I   <-- origin/feature1
```

Now, somehow, `origin` has gained a new commit `J` on (`origin`'s) `feature1`.  So you run `git fetch origin` and your Git sees that their Git's `feature1` is commit `J`, which you don't have.  Your Git asks their Git for `J`; their Git says `J`'s parent is `I`; your Git says *oh I have that already*; and they package up commit `J` and any new files, and send you the package.

Your Git now inserts commit `J` into your repository, and then *updates your `origin/feature1`* to remember that their `feature1` is now pointing to now-shared commit `J`.  You now have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature1
```

Note how none of your *branch* names have changed!  The only things that changed were your `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  This is important, especially if other people are sending commits to `origin`.

Suppose you fetch again the next day, after you've added some commit to your `master`, and they've added some *other* commit to *their* (origin's) `master`.  You'll get:

```
          K   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature1
```

Your `master` doesn't move, so your `master` still remembers your new commit `K`.  Your `origin/master` *does* move so that it remembers their new commit `L`.

#### After `fetch`, incorporate

Now that you've fetched some new commit(s), you might wish to incorporate them into *your* branches.  Suppose we now have this mess:

```
          K   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature1
```

We might want to *combine the work* we did, going from commit `H` to commit `K`, with the work *they* did going from commit `H` to commit `L`.  To do this combining, we can pick either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  These are two very different options and they work differently to produce different results.  There's no particularly strong reason right now to prefer one or the other.  For no particularly good reason, I'm going to illustrate a rebase first, where we take our `K` and copy it to a new-and-improved `K'` whose parent is `L`:

```
            K   ???
           /
          /  K'  <-- master (HEAD)
         /  /
...--G--H--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature1
```

We've abandoned our old commit `K` for this new-and-improved `K'`, which combines our changes (`H`-vs-`K`) with their changes (`H-vs-`L`) and comes after` L`.  Or, we can use` git merge`to combine the work into a new *merge commit*`M`:

```
          K--M   <-- master (HEAD)
         /  /
...--G--H--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature1
```

Either method is fine for combining work.  One results in a two-parent *merge commit*, which we can now have `origin` add on to its `master`; the other results in some set of new-and-supposedly-improved commits that add on to their commits.

#### `git push`

The `git push` command is a lot like `git fetch`, except for two things:

- the data—the new commits and supporting objects—move out of our local repository to the other repository; and
- once that's done, we ask them to set one of their *branch* names.

That is, there is no equivalent of a *remote-tracking name*.  We don't have them set some name that keeps their branch names safe.  We ask them to move their branch names so that they point to *our* new commits that we just handed over.  As long as our commits point back to their existing commits, this move is "safe": it doesn't abandon any commits in *their* repository.  If, however, we made a bad commit and want to *eject* it, we can use `git push --force` to tell them so.  There are a lot of complications here, due to various historical errors as it were, but if we don't need to force-push, we don't have to worry about any of that.  We just send them commits `K` and `M` for instance:

```
          K--M
         /  /
...--G--H--L   [they already have these]
         \
          I--J   [they already have these]
```

and then ask them, politely, if they would please move their `master` from wherever it is now (commit `L`) to point to commit `M` instead.  Since commit `M` keeps commit `L` around, they'll probably obey this polite request.  Once that happens, our Git will update our `origin/master`—our memory of their `master`—and we will change our own repository to look like this:

```
          K--M   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         /  /
...--G--H--L
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature1
```

and you can see that we and they now have the *same commits* and even use the *same name* (`master`) to find commit `M` as the *latest* commit on `master`.

#### Now let's go back to what you're doing

You have, in your GitHub fork, a `staging`:

```
...--P--Q   <-- staging
```

You clone this to your laptop:

```
...--P--Q   <-- staging, origin/staging
```

Now you make some new commit `R` that comes after `Q`:

```
          R   <-- branch1
         /
...--P--Q   <-- staging, origin/staging
```

If you now send commit `R` to your GitHub fork and ask *them* to call it `branch1` too, *they* get this:

```
          R   <-- branch1
         /
...--P--Q   <-- staging
```

and you add the name `origin/branch` to your laptop, also pointing to commit `R`.

If you now raise a *pull request* to `upstream`, *they* get to see commit `R` now.  Commit `R` points back to commit `Q`, which they presumably do have in their repository too.  So the only commit they see as "new" this time, to be introduced to *their* branch that points to `Q`, is commit `R`.

Suppose you now create a new commit `S` on your laptop.  *You* get to pick what parent commit `S` has.  If you pick commit `Q`, your laptop has this graph:

```
          R   <-- branch1
         /
...--P--Q   <-- staging
         \
          S   <-- branch2
```

You now send `S` to your GitHub fork `origin`, with `git push -u origin branch2`.  You can now have GitHub ask `upstream` to add commit `S` via a pull request.  They'll see that the parent of `S` is `Q` so the PR lists just the one commit.

**Or, you can create `S` with parent `R`.**  If you do that, your laptop has this:

```
            S   <-- branch2
           /
          R   <-- branch1
         /
...--P--Q   <-- staging
```

You can now send this to your GitHub fork.  Your GitHub fork already has commit `R` (you sent it earlier), so this just adds one commit again.  But now when you make a PR from `branch2`, your GitHub fork offers `upstream` both commits `R` and `S`.  Sure, they can already see `R` through the `branch1` request.  But just looking at the `branch2` *request*, it says to add *two commits*.

Once they accept the `branch1` request—if they ever do—the PR for `branch2` will only say to *add* one commit because *their* branch will point to commit `R`.  Well, that is, it will *if* they accept that request in one particular way!  The GitHub buttons that accept PRs have three modes, and two of those three modes wind up *copying* commit `R` to a new and different commit, with a different hash ID.

**This is where, and why, your problem shows up:** because a PR really means *take these commits as shown in the commit graph*.  The only way to see what's really going to happen is to view the commit graph.  But *GitHub will not let you see the commit graph.*  They hide it, for reasons both good and bad.

Note that just choosing "commit Q" (the tip of `staging`) as the base each time has its own issues.  Whether they are *big* issues depends on how whoever runs `upstream` accepts PRs: if they use <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> or <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> they're never taking your original commits by hash ID in the first place, so most of these go away (you have a whole different set of issues to deal with instead, which you will have regardless of how they take PRs).  If they use a real merge, which keeps the original commit hash IDs around, they might want you to do your own rebasing into your `origin` GitHub repository, which will require using force-push.

Comment: I didn't know SO had a --verbose option

Answer (score -1):

```
git checkout -b <branch name>
git pull
git push
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes